# SQL Generating combinations of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of columns in an SQL Table. What I would like to do is return all possible combinations of the entries in my table, so: let's say column 1 has "Cat, Dog, Horse", and column 2 has "Red, Green, Blue", I would like to return a table that says:

```
Cat Red
Cat Green
Cat Blue
Dog Red
Dog Green
Dog Blue
Horse Red
Horse Green
Horse Blue
```

and so on.

How could I accomplish this in SQL-Server?

Thanks. I should mention that some of the columns contain different types, so I don't think union would work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a [cross join](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx).

Exemple query :

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

It should produce the result you expect.

If you have a single table (like in your case) you can use aliases like this

```
SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2 FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table1 as table2
```

Comment: A stupid question from a SQL newbie, but I don't have 2 tables, so what would I put in place for Table 2? Thanks.

Comment: You can join a table on itself, usually!

Comment: Ahh. okay, didn't know you could write aliases like that. Thanks!

Comment: As litelite mentioned, you can join the table with itself via either an INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER or FULL OUTER JOIN (recommended). This will be based on what columns are used to join.

Comment: What if you had 3 columns? How would the query change for 3 or 4 columns?

Comment: You would join the table another time (with a new alias). But be careful, the results will grow exponentially every time you add another column

Comment: I would probably want to add a SELECT DISTINCT before the cross join right?

Comment: Depends on whether you source columns are unique or not.